# Deploying tagged builds from Travis-CI to Heroku

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

I am trying to get Travis-CI to automatically deploy a successful tagged build to Heroku. Below is my .travis.yml setup:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  strategy: git
  run:
    - "rake db:migrate"
    - restart
  on:
    tags: true
```

Upon tagging the repository:

```
git tag -a 1.0.0 -m "release 1.0.0"
```

and pushing to the remote repository, Travis-CI kicks off the build but exits immediately after the following:

```
$ git fetch --tags
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

Travis-CI does not deploy the application to Heroku. Am I missing a piece?

Comment: Can you share the link to your travis build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a glitch with `on: tags: true` that the condition is never met and the code will never trigger a deploy. The github issue is [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1675). The issue should be resolved soon, and in the meantime you can use a branch like `releases` to update your heroku app with `on:branch`.

**Update**: 
To fix `on:tags`, you can  do this, as refrenced in the above github issue.

```
 on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to restore `on: tags`.